# Where is the restart option?

Tags: reboot

I just did a fresh install of 11.10  and noticed that the restart option is missing.
Is there a way I can put it or turn this option on?

Comment: I haven't noticed that button just for almost years. You should use your command line as the greatest tool in linux. `sudo shutdown now` for shutting down your machine. `sudo reboot`, etc.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In older versions of Ubuntu, you click the shut down button then click restart:

[image: shut down button]

Comment: when I click the gear icon the options are lock, logout, suspend, hibernate, and shutdown. there is no restart.

Comment: st2011 you have to click the shutdown button first before the restart button appears

Comment: Thank you for some reason didn't see this before.

Comment: I don't understand why they changed this.  It makes no sense to go to Shutdown to go to restart, they're two separate actions.

Comment: @blackn1ght I guess they figure that in order to do a restart, shutting down your machine is part of the process of doing that.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date.

Answer (score 18):

In older versions of Ubuntu that run Unity, you can also type "restart" in the dash.

[image: restart button]

Comment: sweet. This is a nice alternative.

Comment: Doesn't work if you don't have your desktop in english. Actually

Comment: Actually, in french, I have to type `redémarrer` to get the option. `restart`, `reboot` just don't work. Really annoying considering that most commands, program names, options are in english, which i got to learn, and that's not so obvious how it was decided to translate them. Consequence: terminal + `sudo reboot`.

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 21.04 with GNOME Shell.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily restart the computer by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and typing `gksu reboot` into the box that comes up.

Comment: This will work with any version of Ubuntu, AFAIK.

Comment: your could also type "gksu shutdown -r now" :)

Comment: My mouse wasn't working. This worked! :)

Answer (score 4):

OR <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

> sudo shutdown -r now

:)

Comment: That will work in a terminal but I don't think it will work from the dash.

Comment: You could press Alt+F2 and run "gksu shutdown -r now". But outside of situations where the normal ways to restart graphically aren't working, there wouldn't be much benefit.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 21.04, click the power icon in the top right corner of the screen, then click "Power Off/Log Out". In the sub-menu that appears, click "Restart".

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: And if that option is missing too, click Power Off and you will be offered to Restart instead. GAH.