# How do I reboot Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, reboot

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm not familiar with some settings. How do I restart/reboot the system so that I can have the option to use Windows 7 in a Dual Boot.

Comment: start here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot  -  are you using ubuntu live or did you install it already

Comment: If your looking for the restart: 
[ You can check this post.][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66633/where-is-the-restart-option

Answer (score 1):

Click on the cog like icon in the top right, go to shutdown and click restart. Alternatively you could just press the power button and a menu should pop up with an option to reboot.

EDIT: I'm not sure what your question actually is. If you want to reboot into windows, check the comments for your question.

Comment: After 11.10, this option is not present.

Comment: @philipballew Shows up for me (both methods)

Comment: Hum, odd.I believe in some versions policy kit disabled it.

Comment: Works for me too on Precise :S

Answer (score 0):

to restart you have to choose on unity shutdown and the box that appear next have reboot on the left and shutdown on the right.

you can them choose when the  computer start again on the boot menu the option of booting with ubuntu and windows 7 if they are installed ,and if  grub is not update you can update grub or boot ,not sure what is the right terminology, by installing for ubuntu software center  start-up manager.